# MvvmCross.Exceptions.MvxException: Failed to create setup instance

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm upgrading from MvvMCross 5.7 to 6.0.0.

When I try to run the app, it shows the splash screen and just after that, vs2017 gives me the following error:

> MvvmCross.Exceptions.MvxException: Failed to create setup instance

The error always is in the same line, no matter which file I set as mainlauncher.

Example:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat;
using MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Views;

namespace ClaveiSGApp.Droid.Views
{
    [Activity(Label = "App", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainView : MvxAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MainView);
        }
    }
}
```

The error always is in `base.OnCreate(bundle);`

Do you have any ideas?

(Let me know if you need more info/code about something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I few days, searching, seeing gihub files and talking with Nick Randolph as @Ale_lipa suggested.

I noticed that the problem was on the .csproj file under the .Droid project. It was trying to compile files that I manually removed from the project and didn't even exist.

I changed it to match the file that Nick has in [his repository](https://github.com/nickrandolph/MvxPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/blob/master/Mvx-01-TipCalc/TipCalc.Droid/TipCalc.Droid.csproj).

This is the final look:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="SplashScreen.cs" />
    <Compile Include="MainApplication.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Resources\Resource.Designer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Views\FirstView.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 3):

From the error you're getting, it looks like something bad is happening in `CreateSetup` method in `MvxSetupSingleton` ([GitHub](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/e37c07f7908a86241713ea4aac384b2f2f0361bf/MvvmCross/Core/MvxSetupSingleton.cs)). I'm guessing here a bit, but I would assume that there's something wrong with how the `RegisterSetupType<TMvxSetup>` is being called (or it's not being called at all) - you can find this method in `MvxSetup` ([GitHub](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/082ce799a17f31839b7c1221aacc4737942bc58e/MvvmCross/Core/MvxSetup.cs)). Tracking down where the registration happens, it gave me two possible places: `MvxSplashScreenActivity<TMvxAndroidSetup, TApplication>` and `MvxAndroidApplication<TMvxAndroidSetup, TApplication>`.

Going forward with this thinking, and assuming you do use `SplashScreen` in your app. I would suggest updating your `SplashScreen` activity to inherit from `MvxSplashScreenActivity<TMvxAndroidSetup, TApplication>` and check if that helps - you would also need to make your `SplashScreen` is `MainLauncher`. Your code could look like this:

```
[Activity(Label = "FirstDemo.Forms.Splash", Theme = "@style/MainTheme",  MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
public class SplashScreen : MvxFormsSplashScreenAppCompatActivity<MvxFormsAndroidSetup<Core.App, App>, Core.App, App>
{
    public SplashScreen()
         : base(Resource.Layout.SplashScreen)
    {
    }

    protected override void RunAppStart(Bundle bundle)
    {
        StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
        base.RunAppStart(bundle);
    }
}
```

If the above is not clear, check out [blog post by Nick Randolph](https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2018/04/12/MVX0-A-first-MvvmCross-Application.aspx) (a contributor to MvvmCross), that writes about setting up a brand new project with MvvmCross v6. I know you're upgrading - so it's not the same, but you can at least check if you have made all the changes that are required to run the app. Here's [his GitHub repo](https://github.com/nickrandolph/MvxPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/blob/master/Mvx-00-FirstDemo/FirstDemo.Droid/SplashScreen.cs), with the sample code that I pasted in

Comment: Thank you for you're answer, I created another project and tried to follow the steps of the blog but I ran into the same problem. I'm gonna ask the author and if he can solve the issue, I'll mark your answer as accepted

Comment: Sure, do that. I would also suggest, to download his repo from GitHub and try running it. If it works, then make sure your project(s) looks exactely the same

Answer (score 1):

I followed the exact steps on the [blog post series by Nick Randolph](https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2018/04/12/MVX0-A-first-MvvmCross-Application.aspx) referenced in other answers, and received the same problem as the question specifies [`Failed to create setup instance`] but in the Xamarin.Forms article. This was due to mixing code from a different part of the example. My specific issue was because the `ActivityAttribute` that declared `MainLauncher=true` derived from `MvxFormsAppCompatActivity<TViewModel>` instead of `MvxFormsAppCompatActivity<TMvxAndroidSetup, TApplication, TFormsApplication, TViewModel>`  Looks like the OP @Brugui sample code may have had the same flaw.